# Parent and child classes unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python

I was experimenting with parent and child classes in python. I got an error that I can't seem to solve, both the error and code are posted below. If you could post a reason why this is happening and an edit of my code how to fix this it would be much appreciated.

```
# Classes Example
class vehicle():
    def __init__(self,name,weight,wheels,color):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
        self.wheels = wheels
        self.color = color
    def __str__(self):
        return("Hi, iam a vehicle called " + self.name)
    def wow(self):
        return(self.weight/self.wheels)

class car(vehicle):

    def __init__(self,doors,quantity,mpg):
        self.doors = doors
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.mpg = mpg

    def distance(self):
        return(self.quantity/self.mpg)


# Main Program
object1 = vehicle("Audi A3",1000,4,"blue")
print(object1)
print(object1.name)
object1.name = "Audi S3"
print(object1.name)
print(object1.weight)

object2 = vehicle(name = "Claud Butler" , color = "Red" , wheels = 2, weight = 20)
print(object2)
print(object2.wow())

object3 = car(name = "Burty", color = "Pink" , wheels = 3, weight = 500, doors = 3 , quantity = 10, mpg = 1000)
print(object3.color)
print(object3.wow())
print(object3.distance())
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\my documents\Computing\Class example.py", line 39, in <module>
    object3 = car(name = "Burty", color = "Pink" , wheels = 3, weight = 500, doors = 3 , quantity = 10, mpg = 1000)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

Comment: Remember that `__init__` is a method just like any other, and the version in `car` overrides the version in `vehicle`.

Comment: `__init__` is inherited exactly like any other method, and if you leave it out of car, then it uses vehicle's `__init__`. Just tested it, too, to see if I was going mad...

Answer (score 3):

The error is raised in the following line:

```
object3 = car(name = "Burty", color = "Pink" , wheels = 3, weight = 500, doors = 3 , quantity = 10, mpg = 1000)
```

There, you are calling the `car` constructor with (amongst others) a `name` parameter. Now, if you look at the define constructor of the `car` type, you see the following:

```
class car(vehicle):
    def __init__(self,doors,quantity,mpg):
        self.doors = doors
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.mpg = mpg
```

As you can see, there is no `name` parameter in the parameter list.

I assume that you expected the `car` child class to inherit all the constructor parameters from the parent `vehicle` class but that’s not actually the case. Unless you explicitely duplicate those parameters, they won’t be there. You also have to call the parent’s constructor explicitely. All in all, your `car` constructor should look like this:

```
def __init__(self, name, weight, wheels, color, doors, quantity, mpg):
    # call the base type’s constructor (Python 3 syntax!)
    super().__init__(name, weight, weels, color)

    self.doors = doors
    self.quantity = quantity
    self.mpg = mpg
```

Answer (score 0):

The method

```
__init__(self,doors,quantity,mpg):
```

does not have an argument called `name`. If you want it, you should add it.